# send specific parameters in response to server from next view controller using AFNetworking 3.0?

Tags: ios, objective-c

i'm very new in iOS app development.I am going to use AFNetworking 3.0. On first view when i enter mobile no. and click on submit button then it connect with server and i get following response from server:

```
responseData: [{"edriverId":"bd307a3ec329e10a2cff8fb87480823da114f8f4","token":"6uc4d1houfecbmjgy9ezpru9n25nw40b17cwk439j52"}]
```

now my question is,how can i take only that token from responseData and send it to server from next view. Please help me.

NOTE:whenever we call service token changes every time.

my code is:

```
-(void)serverconnection

{

    NSString *Loginurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://24x7tracker.com/busservices/School/DriverPreLogin"];


NSDictionary *params = @{@"mobile":self.phonenumber.text,

                         @"archive":@"schooldb1"

                         };


AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];


manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];


manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

AFSecurityPolicy* policy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate];

[policy setValidatesDomainName:NO];

[policy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];

manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html", nil];

manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json",@"text/html",nil];



manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json",@"text/plain",nil];


[manager POST:Loginurl parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {


    NSLog(@"Json: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

    [self getdata:responseObject];


    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"responseData: %@", str);

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginsegue" sender:self];

}
      failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error)

{

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    UIAlertController *Erroralert=   [UIAlertController

                                      alertControllerWithTitle:@" Network Connection Failed!!"

                                      message:@"Please try again"

                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [self presentViewController:Erroralert animated:YES completion:nil];





    UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction

                                actionWithTitle:@"Ok"

                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault

                                handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)

                                {
                                    [self resignFirstResponder];

                                    [Erroralert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];



                                }];

    [Erroralert addAction: yesButton];


}];


}

-(void)getdata:(NSData *)data

{}
```

Comment: can you show some full code

Comment: see my code ...@Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this in two ways

1. **NSUserDefault**

   ```
   // NSArray *temp = (NSArray *)responseObject;

   NSError *error;
   NSArray *temp = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:&error];

   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[[temp objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"token"] forKey:@"token"];
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginsegue" sender:self];
   ```

on second Page

**Retrieve**

for Retrieve the `String` in `NSUserDefaults` you can directly use `objectForKey`

```
NSString *token = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"token"];
```

2. **Pass the string to second Page like**

*first page create one global value for store the object in string*

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)          NSString *tokenString;
```

*serilize the response object and store in the global value which one you need*

```
                   NSError *error;
 NSArray *temp = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:&error];

     // in this line we assingn the current value to global value
     tokenString = [[temp objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"token"];
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginsegue" sender:self];
```

*on that destination view controller create one global value for pass the current string*

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)          NSString *fetchtokenString;
```

*on that first VC the prepareForSegue method pass the globalized value to second page*

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

secondViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
// pass the current object to second page value
vc.fetchtokenString = tokenString;
```

*finally second VC you can get the value on viewDidload page*

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
 NSLog (@"token value ==%@",fetchtokenString);
}
```

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik...its not work..i got error like: - [_NSInlineData objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7863f770
2016-05-18 11:42:11.185 BusTrkr[798:20925] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSInlineData objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7863f770'

Comment: @SurajSukale -- just wait I modify the answer

Comment: @SurajSukale - print this `NSArray *temp = (NSArray *)responseObject;` once bro

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik can you please explain me the second way to send value to another viewcontroller ..if you can ?

Comment: @vaibhav - in which line do u not understand

Comment: @Mahesh - I agree you reply , are you seen this `responseData: [{"edriverId":"bd307a3ec329e10a2cff8fb87480823da114f8f4","token":"6uc4d1houfecbmjgy9ezpru9n25nw40b17cwk439j52"}]`, it is start with array or dictionary bro

Comment: Hey friend @Anbu.Kartik ...i got again this error....-[_NSInlineData objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a1404a0
2016-05-18 11:53:29.410 BusTrkr[881:23878] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSInlineData objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a1404a0'

Comment: actually i always used nsuserdefalut to pass values so i need to understand whole concept ..

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik.Please suggest me answer friend... i got error that in both case(using userdefault or in this also)

Comment: @SurajSukale - problem in this line `NSArray *temp = (NSArray *)responseObject;` can you print the temp once what the output you got

Comment: @SurajSukale did you check your response is not in valid json format ?

Comment: @vaibhav - the json is valid bro, if sukale print the temp object we can get the output

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik.... i got that error and on the line         _tokenString = [[temp objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"token"];
it shows like ...... signal SIGABRT

Comment: @SurajSukale - just print the `temp` result

Comment: @SurajSukale use code  **NSDictionary *dict = [returnString JSONValue];
NSString *status = [dictMain valueForKey:@"token"];**  
**you need to use SBJson lib to call JSONValue method** if you comfortable to use NSDictionary ..

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik......temp result is like this..... temp=<5b7b2265 64726976 65724964 223a2262 64333037 61336563 33323965 31306132 63666638 66623837 34383038 32336461 31313466 38663422 2c22746f 6b656e22 3a22787a 7a626d76 6f697977 6376327a 336c6e31 6361656d 6c637773 746c666b 6b626968 71613469 62377865 36227d5d>

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik...please see this question.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315226/how-to-send-background-location-to-server-periodically-if-location-change-or-not/37315807#37315807

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follow

Parse ur response like this

```
 NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject];
```

Get your token in one global `variable` suppose

```
NSString *token = [json objectForkey:@"token"];
```

When you push next `UIViewController`, set this value as property of next `UIViewController`. For that, you need to create one `property` of type `NSString` in next `UIViewController` like:

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *token;
```

Access that propery in first `UIViewController` like this.
You have to add following line before pushing the next `UIViewControler`

```
sectionViewControllerObject.token = token //variable of first UIViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

@Anbu.Karthik if you want to send the value from First view controller to Second view controller then you can do in many of ways either you can use `segue` or `delegate` or `NSnotification`.

I am doing in **swift** for only getting the token data just try this using **objective C.**

```
var myArray: NSMutableArray = [["edriverId":"1234","token":"anytokenid"]]

print(myArray)

var parsedata:String = myArray.objectAtIndex(0).valueForKey("token")as!String

print(parsedata)
```